# Convert PostGIS to MBTiles on Windows

Tags: postgis, windows, mbtiles

What is the simplest way to convert PostGIS tables from a database to MBTiles?

I have a PostgreSQL server with PostGIS extension, and I have a database called "mydatabase", with spatial table "s_table" and geometry column called "way".

I just want to create MBTiles file that contains all the objects from s_table and save it in file in Windows.

Does anybody have a precise solution for this problem?

Comment: If PostGIS version is 2.5+ you can use ST_AsMVT https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/dynamic-vector-tiles-from-postgis has examples how to.

Comment: That fuction is used for creating vector tiles, not MBTiles, right?